# Unable to implement JMS using ApacheMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Iam trying to implement a simple JMS(traditional not using springs) code in eclipse using ApacheMQ.

I have downloaded the ApacheMQ from [apache.org](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/activemq/apache-activemq/5.4.3/apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin.zip) and sample JMS sender from [SimpleQueueSender](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq/maven/4.1.2/activemq-core/xref-test/org/apache/activemq/demo/SimpleQueueSender.html) and receiver from [SimpleQueueReceiver](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq/maven/4.1.2/activemq-core/xref-test/org/apache/activemq/demo/SimpleQueueReceiver.html) respectively.

Now how should i execute this code? I have already gone through all related tutorials but couldnot find answers to these questions.

Please suggest solutions on

1. What all are the changes to be done regarding classpaths,settings after the activemq is started as below

INFO | jetty-7.1.6.v20100715
INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole initialized.
INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
INFO | ActiveMQ Console at http://0.0.0.0:8161/admin
INFO | ActiveMQ Web Demos at http://0.0.0.0:8161/demo
INFO | RESTful file access application at http://0.0.0.0:8161/fileserver
INFO | Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8161

how to proceed next?

2.Should this server be added in the eclipse as a new server and then the program is run on that server?

3.Can these programs be run from eclipse or should they executed from a separate console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that you have included all required jars for ActiveMQ, include default activemq-all.jar in your  eclipse Project's buildpath

ActiveMQ can be started independent of your eclipse environment.

To answer your questions:-

(1) In your JMS application use following properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:61616
```

you may use IP address or 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost`

(2) No need to add mq server(broker) in eclipse.

(3) A simple jms client can run from eclipse run menu given that you have set the Java build path appropriately.

Comment: Thanks but i think iam missing on some more jars the above two lines when added are showing error that java.naming cannot be resolved..:( and also RHS of "java.naming.factory.initial".Please help on what iam missing now?

Comment: Try to use some server run time library (like JBoss ...) as part of your project. This will have all necessary libraries for naming

Comment: Thanks it wrks fine with activemq-all-5.4.1 but does not with activemq-all-5.5.1.It is wrking till connection is establieshed but failing from session creation using later jar.Should any other jars also be included while using 5.5.1? Plz help :(

Answer (score 1):

While you download ActiveMQ. you will find different sever(Message Broker) of each Operating System(windows,Linux,Mac). If you using Window then go to start server for Window OS.While ActiveMQ message Broker is running you can open url http://localhost:8161/admin for administration and http://localhost:8161/demo for demonstration.

you can find these java demos under webapp folder.

I have worked JMS with spring using ActiveMQ. So if you want to create example JMS application then Spring In Action 3.0 is best book.

You need not to add Message Broker(Server) inside the eclipse just run this outside. and please specify brokerUrl as "tcp://localhost:61616" and  define destination topic or destination queue which one you implemented.

Comment: Thanks but can you help me understand the difference of using JMS with and without springs? does a receiver using JMS with spring be able to receive messages from sender who implements JMS without springs and vice versa?or would there be any other issues?

Comment: Actually spring is built upon java JMS. Spring provide jmsTemplate which you can use as sender as well as reciever.

you can either use jmsTemplate for send or recieve message. No matter whether message comes from with spring or without spring you can recieve message using jmsTemplate. But destination for topic or queue must be same.